# Facebook Mobile App Installations don't show any thing

Tags: android, facebook

I want to track installs with mobile app ads. I already register my app and add Facebook SDK. But, I can't see any installation in App Insights. So, what's my problem and how do I test it. Here is my main activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.facebook.AppEventsLogger;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }

     protected void onResume() {
           super.onResume();

           AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this, "APP_ID");
           AppEventsLogger.newLogger(this).flush();
     }

}
```

Please advise if I have any error. Thanks a lots for your support.